# What can I use custom CloudWatch metrics for?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

What can I do by creating custom CloudWatch metrics?
I couldn't get the idea behind creating custom metrics in CloudWatch after I read the docs.

I’ve created a new metric:

```
mon-put-data --metric-name MyMetric --namespace "MyService" --value 2 --timestamp 2011-03-14T12:00:00.000Z
```

What can I get from this metric?
I couldn't understand the custom metrics.

Answer (score 6):

A common case and example for the use of custom metrics is about instance memory reporting.

There are several codes around the web about custom CloudWatch metrics. I found this very useful into Amazon Forums.

```
#!/bin/bash

export AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME=/home/ec2-user/CloudWatch-1.0.12.1
export AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=$AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME/credentials
export AWS_CLOUDWATCH_URL=https://monitoring.amazonaws.com
export PATH=$AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre

# get ec2 instance id
instanceid=`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

memtotal=`free -m | grep 'Mem' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
memfree=`free -m | grep 'buffers/cache' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4`
let "memused=100-memfree*100/memtotal"

mon-put-data --metric-name "FreeMemoryMBytes" --namespace "System/Linux" --dimensions "InstanceId=$instanceid" --value "$memfree" --unit "Megabytes"

mon-put-data --metric-name "UsedMemoryPercent" --namespace "System/Linux" --dimensions "InstanceId=$instanceid" --value "$memused" --unit "Percent"
```

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=266893

Answer (score 5):

> Amazon CloudWatch provides a reliable, scalable, and flexible
>   monitoring solution that you can start using within minutes. You no
>   longer need to set up, manage, or scale your own monitoring systems
>   and infrastructure. Using Amazon CloudWatch, you can easily monitor as
>   much or as little metric data as you need. Amazon CloudWatch lets you
>   programmatically retrieve your monitoring data, view graphs, and set
>   alarms to help you troubleshoot, spot trends, and take automated
>   action based on the state of your cloud environment.

This is a web service like the rest of Amazon Web Services. You can work with it through an API as well as through the Console. You can also integrate it with other services like Simple Notification Service (SNS) and even Auto-Scaling your instances.

The idea of the custom metric mechanism is to allow you to extend the build-in metrics that are provided by AWS to ones that are either not accessible to AWS (like your memory and disk status), or are relevant to your business (size of purchase, user demographic...).

CloudWatch is scalable and reliable service that you don't need to install nor manage.

Another important feature is the ability to set up alarms on your metrics. For example, you can send you an email when a threshold on your metric is reached (you sold more than 1,000 items in a day, for example).

Now, with the addition of Lambda, you are having even more option to use the CloudWatch Metrics and Alarms. You can subscribe a Lambda function to an alarm based on a custom metric, and react to such events in real time automatically. See here for an example to auto scale your Docker environment in Elastic Container Service (ECS): https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scaling-amazon-ecs-services-automatically-using-amazon-cloudwatch-and-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 3):

The idea of CloudWatch is to collect metrics from running cloud resources (servers, applications, databases, etc.) and share this information among other resources, in order to let them make decisions. For example, your application may produce the following metrics:

- size of in-memory queue
- memory available for JVM
- disk space available for cache
- users currently active
- transactions per minute
- $ sales per hour

In an extreme case you can even reproduce Google Analytics with CloudWatch. It's a convenient instrument to collect statistics and distribute it.

Comment: Ok.. For example let us take the case `users currently active`. How the data get to CloudWatch.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this particular case, where custom metrics were very helpful:
I have an application whit several instances, and I'm sending logs to CloudWatch (different log streams per instance). Then I needed to create some alarms depending on the Errors logs. The problem is that the existing metrics for Logs are: "IncomingLogEvents" and "IncomingBytes", and none of those helps me with that.

In my solution (Python code below), I created a metric to count the number of errors in each stream:

**The structure of the message I log is**:

```py
log = {
    'log_group': '<log_group>',
    'log_stream': '<instance_log_stream>',
    'level': '<levelname>',  # "level" could be INFO|WARNING|ERROR
    'logger': '<instance name>',
    'message': '<message>'
}
```

**The creation of the Metric Filter**:

Notice that I'm creating dimensions to group/separate the metric per each particular instance stream. The value of those dimensions are related to the fields from the message.

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('logs')

client.put_metric_filter(
       logGroupName='<log_group>',
       filterName='error-logs-count',
       filterPattern="{$.level = \"ERROR\"}",
       metricTransformations=[
            {
                'metricNamespace': '<namespace>',
                'metricName': 'IncomingErrorLogs',
                'metricValue': '1',
                'dimensions': {
                    'LogGroupName': '$.log_group',
                    'StreamName': '$.log_stream'
                },
                'unit': 'Count'
            },
        ])
```

**The final metrics**:

With that, I can use the created metric to create alarms when there are errors in certain instance_stream.

[image]

In conclusion, the custom metrics could be helpful for any particular thing that you want to measure from the messages in your logs.